# Custom Labels usage - IntelliJ

Tags: illuminatedcloud

I've been trying out Illuminated Cloud in IntelliJ lately, and i saw that it does not recognise Labels. Normally I would have wrote `Label.Example` to get that string from my org, but they are not being recognised, and marked as red.

Comment: You need to retrieve labels' metadata to IDE and it will recognize them.

Comment: I did, and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using SFDX, but rather have a traditional developer project, you need to make sure your package.xml includes subscription to the custom labels. Once subscribed a retrieve metadata will pull your labels down and they will be available for auto-completion and other intellisense functionality.

If you are already subscribed then I recommend doing a full regeneration of the Offline Symbol Table and a reload of the project.

If you are using SFDX, you need to do a pull to get the labels off the scratch org (if that is where you created them). Again, regenerate the OST if necessary.

Comment: Thanks!, it seems that when not retrieving Custom Labels at project creation you need to set few things more than just checking them in subscription and retrieval!